# Minecraft sounds not working using javaw

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

I've being trying to get Minecraft sounds working lately without success using javaw.exe, but strange enough with the console oupout (java.exe) my sounds are working. Since this is just a workarround and doesn't solve the issue itself, I would like to know if any of you know what could be causing this problem.

I have no sound anywhere including main menu and f3 + s isn't doing anything.

Yes I did try to re-install Java on my machine (when defined Minecraft launcher to use the JRE installed on my machine), I tried to re-install the game and I tried to check if sounds were working using the javasounddemo that I downloaded on Oracle website (it works).

Here is a installation log of minecraft latest version using javaw.exe: https://pastebin.com/cNVnTWVN .

Comment: Just some random ideas: Did you turn off audio for that process using the system settings? What warnings are in the log? Does the same happen with 1.12.2? Do both ways of starting use the same JVM arguments, .minecraft folder, etc.? Does OBS or some other application (or the sound settings of the OS) show desktop audio being played?

Answer (score 1):

## METHOD 1: Reinstalling Java

1. On your Computer, Uninstall Java.
2. Go To: https://java.com/en/ and click **"Free Java Download"**.
3. Go To your Download Directory Location *(Example: C:\Users\USERNAME\Downloads)*.
4. Click on the Java Setup & Follow the On-Screen Instructions.
5. Uninstall Minecraft. ***[WARNING: Backup your Minecraft if you want to save Worlds, etc..]***
6. Go To https://minecraft.net & on the Top-Left, click **"DOWNLOAD"**.
7. Go To your Download Directory Location *(Example: C:\Users\USERNAME\Downloads)*.
8. Click on the Minecraft Installer & Follow the On-Screen Instructions.
9. Start Minecraft and Start a World and See if the Problem is Solved.

## METHOD 2: Sound Settings

1. Go To your **Control Panel\Hardware and Sound** and click **Sound**.
2. Make sure ALL Devices Connected are Working Properly.
3. Start Minecraft and Go to your Options Menu.
4. Make Sure your Sounds are at **%100** and your Master Volume is at **%100**.
5. Start a World and See if the Problem is Solved.
6. If this did NOT Solve your Problem, then attempt **METHOD 1: Reinstalling Java** Above.

## METHOD 3: Reinstalling Windows

1. If you are **Desperate** for Sound on Minecraft, then *Reinstall Windows*
2. Go To https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/.../windows-reset-or-reinstall-windows-10
3. Follow the Instructions & Reinstall Windows.
4. Go To your **Internet Explorer** or **Microsoft Edge** and Go To https://www.google.com/chrome/ & Install Google Chrome.
5. Go To https://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/ & Install Adobe Flash Player. **[WARNING: Uncheck Optional Downloads in the *Middle Section* on the *Download Page*, Scroll Down to know Why you MUST Download Adobe Flash Player**.
6. Go To your Download Directory Location *(Example: C:\Users\USERNAME\Downloads)*.
7. Click on the Adobe Flash Setup & Follow the On-Screen Instructions.
8. Go To https://minecraft.net & on the Top-Left, click **"DOWNLOAD"**.
9. Go To your Download Directory Location *(Example: C:\Users\USERNAME\Downloads)*.
10. Click on the Minecraft Installer & Follow the On-Screen Instructions.
11. **[OPTIONAL]:** Upload your Minecraft Backup.
12. Download ANY Mods, Texture Packs, or Skins you wanted for Minecraft.
13. Start Minecraft and Start a World and See if the Problem is Solved.

**[NOTE: You MUST Download Adobe Flash Player because Most Games *Require* Adobe Flash Player.]**

**[NOTE: You MUST Download Java because Minecraft *REQUIRES* Java to Run.]**

*If NONE of these Methods Work, then Please Reply and I will Research to Find More Possible Ways to Solve This Problem.*

Comment: I dont think this really answers the question. The OP isnt asking how can I fix it, they are more asking why does this happen. In any case, they have already done all the steps mentioned in Method 1, and Method 3 seems like way overkill just cause sounds wont play for one game.

Comment: Well, that is unfortunate... But i do not like taking my time and making an answer to Possibly solving the problem he is having and get a dislike for it. I spent over an hour, and that does solve the problem for most people coming in with the same question. But his issue may be a problem with the coding of Minecraft with Javaw

Comment: Dont get me wrong, it is a good answer, and obviously shows a lot of research effort. Im sure it would effectively fix the problem, the point I was making was specifically the OP asked, "I would like to know if any of you know what could be causing this problem." Im sure the follow up question to that would be how do I fix the issue, to which your answer would more than suffice.

Comment: Alright, i see your point. Wish that helped.

Comment: Just elaborating on Kyle's point, Check out the how to answer page: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

*This answer applied only to windows - if you are using Unix you would need to use different commands*

After quick search in launcher logs you would notice this:

`12:45:23    dgr Thread-2    info    Initializing No Sound
12:45:23    dgr Thread-2    info    (Silent Mode)
12:45:23    dgr Thread-2    info    OpenAL initialized.`

This is mostly caused by OpenAL loading error. Detailed error would be shown in actual game logs witch should be included in such situtations.

But why this happens ? OpenAL could error while loading due to multiple issues:

1. Mojang shipped wrong OpenAL library - they did it in past, they could do it now.
2. Mismatch between in java version that are used by game or launcher - launcher downloads binaries based on its java, not one that is used to start-up game ( Depends on launcher version - Notch's old launcher uses same java instance to launch game )
3. Another OpenAL.dll library somewhere in java's libpath. This case is pretty rare but can happen with some software that uses java "in wrong way"

First case isn't applicable for you as sound does work with `java.exe` , but doesn't with `javaw.exe` .

As for second one - you reinstalling java doesn't do much! Your old version is still there and it could be defined in %PATH%! This is why `where.exe` comes in play:

1. Open up any command prompt that you like.
2. Type in `where.exe java` and `where.exe javaw`. `.exe` part is required if you are using PowerShell!
3. Compare output of both commands - it should be semi-equal

Also including game logs could help finding issue as there are many more OpenAL errors that can happen.